# react native socket programming when socket.io.on method is called then this.state is undedined

Tags: react-native

getting error when this method is called using socket

componentDidMount() {

```
 var backapi = api.Backend_API();
 var db = this.state.data;
 console.log("componentDidMount", this.state.data)
  socket.on('notification',
  function (notification) {
    console.log("avi", notification);
    fetch(backapi + "event/eventname/" + notification.event_id, {
      method: 'GET',
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((d) => {
        this.setState({
          data: d
        })
      })
    fetch(backapi + "user/getUserById/" + notification.created_by, {
      method: 'GET'
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("username socket", data);
      })
  })
```

}

getting error this.setState is undefined when this method is called using socket

Comment: please help  me.

Answer (score 2):

The function passed to `socket.on('notification', ...)` handler gets executed from different context so the value of `this` is different. Therefore you have to bind explicitly the context to the function by using the [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) operator or just passing in an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```
socket.on('notification', (notification) => {    
   ...
});
```

Comment: @Ranjeet happy to help you, you can mark my answer as correct if it answered your question, thanks